# undefined method `src' for nil:NilClass Rails LinkThumbnailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, null, thumbnails

Hi folks I am working on applying image preview of a link that you would post.

```
<%= image_tag LinkThumbnailer.generate((post.content).match(/(^$)|(^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(([0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?$)/ix)).images.first.src.to_s if LinkThumbnailer.generate((post.content).match(/(^$)|(^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(([0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?$)/ix)).images.first.src.to_s? %>
```

After posting a link to 2 websites the following error would be thrown at me:

> undefined method `src' for nil:NilClass

What could be causing this error to happen?

Thanks, Connor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I means that method `#images` returns an empty array/collection, so `#first` returns `nil`. You need to check why `#images` doesn't return anything.